# how to call another window in pyqt4 python?

Tags: python, pyqt4

how to call another window in pytq4?
For example i have two separate form. I want to show the second form when i click a button in the login form.

EDITED:
for example i have this dialog for my login.
when the user click a button the main.py would appear and this dialog will be close.

LOGIN.py
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(379, 184)
        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 130, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("accepted()"), Dialog.accept)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("rejected()"), Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

MAIN.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(595, 315)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Comment: At some point, you need to call form.show() to make the other form appear. It's hard to be more specific with so few details about your program.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and this is what I've done. Does not feel like the ideal solution but it worked for me.

```
            import Main
            self.main = Main.Form(user, loginWindow=self)

            self.hide()        
            self.main.show()

            # You can do self.close() here OR
            # loginWindow.close() from Main.py
            self.close()
```

Main.py

```
class Form(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, user,  parent=None, loginWindow=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        # etc...
```

Comment: ive tried your code but it gives me an error, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Form'

Comment: Here's my Main.py class definition `class Form(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, user,  parent=None, loginWindow=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)`